# Comparing user input to a number with leading zero

Tags: javascript, leading-zero

Consider the following code:

```
var a = 011;

ans = prompt("enter password", "");

if (a == ans) {
   alert("done");
} else {
   alert("false");
}
```

Why does `console.log(a)` outputs 9?

What should I enter as a password into the prompt to have `alert("done");` called?

Comment: A leading zero on a number means Javascript interprets it as Octal, ie base 8.  11 octal == 9 decimal.

Comment: 011 is the octal representation of 9

Comment: `a` is coming out as `9` because of the leading `0` in `011`. That's storing it in memory as a base-8 number, which in decimal is 9.

Comment: a password as a number is not a good idea.

Comment: and a password stored in a client-side script is even worst

Comment: @DanielA.White It is just question I am not gonna to use this on production .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd get the same result with `parseInt("011", 8)`. That is an integer literal starting with a `0` is seen as `octal` (see [the MDN on integer literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Integers)).

Remove the `0` and you'll be fine.

If what you want is a string, here's the correct literal:

```
var a = "011";
```

Answer (score 3):

The leading `0` means octal in JavaScript.

Comment: and what about second part

Comment: @YAM javascript isn't strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want octal then make it a string

```
var a = '011';
```

Entering 011 will then give you 'Done'

Answer (score 1):

`0 =>` This means octal, so that's why you are getting alert false;

```
var a = 011;

ans = prompt("enter password","");

if (a==ans){
  alert("done");
 }else{
  alert("false")
}
```

`var a = "011"` will alert out `done`;

From the Documentation:

> 1. If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
>      (hexadecimal).
> 2. If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This
>      feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do
>      not support it (instead using the radix 10). For this reason always
>      specify a radix when using parseInt.
> 3. If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>      (decimal).
> 4. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt
>      returns NaN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt